# Scss/sass styles not being applied even with class being added

Tags: html, jquery, sass

I have a function that adds the class `active` on click.

The problem is that I can see the class being added on click upon `inspect` the browser but the actual style isn't being applied.

See my code below

HTML

```
<div class="header">
</div>
<div class="modal-wrapper">                     
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(".header").on("click", function (){
    const wrapper = $(".modal-wrapper");
    wrapper.addClass(".active");
});
```

Scss

```
.modal-wrapper{
    &.active{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%; 
        position: fixed; 
        background-color: #444; 
        top: 0; 
        left:0; 
        z-index:4444;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try with another css (not scss) class name? I guess it's because scss isn't compiling correctly.

Comment: tried as new css class `.canx-active` and still not applied. Console/inspect shows as `<div class="modal-wrapper .canx-active"></div>`

Comment: `wrapper.addClass(".active");` should be `wrapper.addClass("active");` with no leading `.` in the CSS class name

Comment: @RandomDeveloper as Phuzi says, it has to be `wrapper.addClass("active");`

Answer (score 0):

There small syntax error in your code,  remove . from calss "active" class name

```
wrapper.addClass(".active");
```

Changed to

```
wrapper.addClass("active");
```

Working Js Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/katheer_mizal/qb4zwa1k/3/